# loadrunner, Can I view the value of a web_reg_save_param during replay

Tags: loadrunner

Eg replay via F10 (Step by Step) 
.. Without performing a parameter substitution in the script, and looking in the replay log.

Ideally Id like to see the value I saved at the point the parameter is registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lr_message(); or lr_output_message; or (my preference) lr_debug_message(); if you want to output to the log yourself.  Or, you may turn to the run time settings advanced log items for variable substitution.   Turning this on will show you when a correlation value is collected and its value even before you use it later.

Comment: Thanks James, I had just got to the advanced log settings under my own steam - I should have checked back here earlier!